# Need to add a class of highlight to a <p> element that's an immediate previous sibling of the button being clicked

Tags: javascript, html

Can some one walk me through this please? Im having a hard time understanding  what they are asking me to do

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
    <script>
    var list = document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];
    
    list.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      if (e.target.tagName == 'BUTTON') {
       
      }
    });</script>
            <title>JavaScript and the DOM</title>
        </head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
        <body>
            <section>
                <h1>Making a Webpage Interactive</h1>
                <p>Things to Learn</p>
                <ul>
                    <li><p>Element Selection</p><button>Highlight</button></li>
                    <li><p>Events</p><button>Highlight</button></li>
                    <li><p>Event Listening</p><button>Highlight</button></li>
                    <li><p>DOM Traversal</p><button>Highlight</button></li>
                </ul>
            </section>
            
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You are being asked to add a class named `highlight` to the `<p>` element that comes immediately before the clicked button. ie. If the first button was clicked, you should add the `highlighted` class to `<p>Element Selection</p>`.

Comment: @RyanWilson [previousSibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/previousSibling) would be simpler.

Comment: Your answer would also fail to fulfil the requirement if there was an element between `p` and `button`.  _"...<p> element that's an **immediate previous sibling** of the <button>..."_

Comment: @ObeJuarez If an element was to be placed between the `button` and the `p` would you still want to highlight the `p`? ie. If you added a `span` between the `p` and the `button` would you still want to highlight the `p`?

Answer (score 0):

If you can clarify that you only ever want to highlight if the immediate previous sibling is a p element then use:

```
 if(e.target.previousElementSibling.tagName && e.target.previousElementSibling.tagName === "P"){
    e.target.previousElementSibling.classList.add('highlighted');
 }
```

If you are always wanting to only highlight if the sibling before the button is a p tag else don't highlight anything, then use the suggested way by `Turnip` and `connexo`, else if you just want to find the closest p to the button and highlight, the for loop I added below will work.

```js
//Add the click event listener, if the target is the button
//get the parent and find the first child of tagName p
//and add the class
document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0].addEventListener('click', function(e){
     if(e.target.tagName === "BUTTON"){
        
        //use the following to iterate the children and find the closest
        //most immediate p element before the button which is clicked
        //Since we need to be specific and find the immediate p tag before the button
         let closestPreviousPElement = null;
         for(let i = 0; i < e.target.parentNode.children.length; i++){
             if(e.target.parentNode.children[i].tagName === "P"){
                 closestPreviousPElement = e.target.parentNode.children[i];
             }else if(e.target.parentNode.children[i].isSameNode(e.target) && closestPreviousPElement !== null){
                  closestPreviousPElement.classList.add('highlighted');
             }
         }
     }
});
```

```css
.highlighted{
   background-color: #FFFF00;
}
```

```html
        <head>
        <title>JavaScript and the DOM</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <section>
                <h1>Making a Webpage Interactive</h1>
                <p>Things to Learn</p>
                <ul>
                    <li><p>Element Selection</p><button>Highlight</button></li>
                    <li><p>Events</p><button>Highlight</button></li>
                    <li><p>Event Listening</p><button>Highlight</button></li>
                    <li><p>DOM Traversal</p><button>Highlight</button></li>
                </ul>
            </section>       
        </body>
```

Comment: Why so complicated? Why not just check `e.target.previousElementSibling`?

Comment: `if(e.target.previousElementSibling.tagName === 'P') { e.target.previousElementSibling.classList.add('highlighted'); }` or to make it failsafe in case there is no previous element `if(e.target.previousElementSibling.tagName && e.target.previousElementSibling.tagName === 'P') { e.target.previousElementSibling.classList.add('highlighted'); }`

Comment: @connexo I understand what you are offering. If an element was placed between the button and the p it wouldn't highlight anything.

Comment: Which would satisfy the requirement. Then it's no longer an immediate previous sibling.

Comment: @connexo Based on the example, I am not 100% sure that is true. The OP may have used that terminology based on his example. The terminology may change if the hypothetical was to happen. Hoping for more clarification.